# Move Xml tags inside new tag with Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, domparser

This is the xml sample

```
<credentials>
    <user>Jack</user>
    <password>123</password>
    <user>Marcus</user>
    <password>456</password>
    <tag>
    </tag>
    <test>abc</test>
    <details>def</details>
</credentials>
```

I would like to move the "test" and "details" tag inside "tag".

This is the desired result

```
<credentials>
    <user>Jack</user>
    <password>123</password>
    <user>Marcus</user>
    <password>456</password>

    <tag>
    <test>abc</test>
    <details>def</details>
    </tag>
</credentials>
```

How can i do this with Java DOM Parser?

Comment: You tried posting a similarly [overly broad question two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52363393/290085).  I've now closed that as a duplicate of this question.   Please read [ask].  Then [edit] this question and improve it by showing what you've tried and how the results are not meeting your expectations.  If you do not improve your question, it will be closed as being **too broad** and you won't get the help you seek.  Thanks.